# Filtering table data based on multiple conditions from sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have 6 listboxes and three date textboxes which I'm using to apply conditional  filtering on a database table.
What I need is if I select only a single textbox or a listbox value, or multiple listbox values and multiple date values I should be able to retrieve data based on only selected filter conditions from front end. The date or listbox values that I don't select should be skipped.

I have the following query but its not working.How should i write the query?

```
SELECT (MPMST.partyname + '' + ',' + '' + MPMST.contactperson) AS NAME
      ,(MPMST.email + '' + ',' + '' + MPMST.phone) AS ContactDetail
      ,MPMST.address
      ,(MPMST.city + '' + ',' + '' + MPMST.area) AS city_area
      ,MPMST.Already_Computer
      ,MPMST.software
      ,visit_time
      ,visit_purpose
      ,interaction
FROM    MPMST
INNER
JOIN    MCall   ON  MPMST.Partycode = MCall.Partycode
WHERE  MCall.calltype IN ('SUP001')
AND MPMST.area IN ('pavai')
AND MPMST.city  IN ('mumbai')
AND MCall.Date >= CONVERT(DATETIME ,'01/01/2014' ,103)
AND MCall.Date <= CONVERT(DATETIME ,'31/01/2014' ,103) MCall.status = ''
AND MPMST.software = ''
AND MPMST.Software <> ''
AND MPMST.City IS NOT NULL
AND MPMST.Area IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: What does "its not working" mean?

Comment: its not giving me the proper results.my previous query was         WHERE MCall.calltype IN ('SUP001')
OR MPMST.area IN ('pavai')
OR MPMST.city  IN ('mumbai')
AND 
OR MCall.status = ''
OR MPMST.software = ''
AND MPMST.Software <> ''
AND MPMST.City IS NOT NULL
AND MPMST.Area IS NOT NULL..this query gave me only the records satisfying the first condition i.e..'Sup001'

Comment: So then please **show us** the results you're getting, and explain why those aren't the *proper* results - what did you expect insteaD?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly so your solution is :
First you should create Store Procedure like :

```
Create Procedure MPMST_SELECT
(
@P_calltype varchar(200) = Null,
@P_area varchar(200) = Null,
@P_city varchar(200) = Null,
@P_MCallFromDate Date = Null,
@P_MCallToDate Date = Null,
@P_software varchar(200) = Null
)
AS
Begin
SELECT (MPMST.partyname + '' + ',' + '' + MPMST.contactperson) AS NAME
      ,(MPMST.email + '' + ',' + '' + MPMST.phone) AS ContactDetail
      ,MPMST.address
      ,(MPMST.city + '' + ',' + '' + MPMST.area) AS city_area
      ,MPMST.Already_Computer
      ,MPMST.software
      ,visit_time
      ,visit_purpose
      ,interaction
FROM    MPMST
INNER
JOIN    MCall   ON  MPMST.Partycode = MCall.Partycode
WHERE  MCall.calltype ISNUll(@P_calltype,MCall.calltype)
AND MPMST.area  = ISNUll(@P_area,MPMST.area)
AND MPMST.city  = ISNULL(@P_city,MPMST.city)
AND MCall.Date between ISNULL(@P_MCallFromDate, MCall.Date)and ISNULL(@P_MCallToDate,MCall.Date)
AND MPMST.software = ISNULL(@P_software,MPMST.software)
END
```

Now you can run this script like :

```
MPMST_SELECT 'SUP001','pavai',Null,'01/01/2014','31/01/2014',Null
```

Comment: thanks for ur solution but i m using "IN" for calltype,area and city not "=" operator..

Comment: Ya you can use dynamic query in the store procedure for this purpose like :                                                      @P_calltype = 'SUP001,SUP002,SUP002' and use like :
MCall.calltype in '('+ISNUll(@P_calltype,MCall.calltype)+')'